# GCC 5, 6 and 7 on OSX do not support uint

Tags: c++, macos, gcc

I installed GCC 5, 6 and 7 on OSX 10.12 with Homebrew. Compiling the simple code

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    uint foo = 10;
    std::cout << foo << std::endl;
}
```

returns an error:

```
$ g++-7 -o uint uint.cpp
uint.cpp: In function 'int main()':
uint.cpp:5:5: error: 'uint' was not declared in this scope
     uint foo = 10;
     ^~~~
uint.cpp:5:5: note: suggested alternative: 'int'
     uint foo = 10;
     ^~~~
     int
uint.cpp:6:18: error: 'foo' was not declared in this scope
     std::cout << foo << std::endl;
                  ^~~
uint.cpp:6:18: note: suggested alternative: 'feof'
     std::cout << foo << std::endl;
                  ^~~
                  feof
```

This error does not happen with other compilers I have access to. The code works fine with clang++ (on OSX) and with gcc4/5/6 on Linux systems.
Is there a configuration switch missing on my side? Or could this be because gcc links with libstdc++ and not with libc++ which is standard on OSX?

Comment: `uint` is not a keyword and [stdint.h](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdint) doesn't declare it. Where do you think it should come from?

Comment: What do you think `uint` is? There are types in the forms `uintN_t`, `uint_leastN_t`, and `uint_fastN_t`, but not just `uint` by itself.

Comment: Well I can do a `typedef uint unsigned int` but that does not answer my question.

Comment: The flag you are looking for is `-Duint="unsigned int"`. I'm joking of course... but it does work.

Comment: I was almost starting to question my sanity... And your hint does not work: `uint.cpp:5:5: error: cannot combine with previous 'type-name' declaration
      specifier`

Comment: Looks like you forgot `#include "uint.h"`.

Comment: Although I wouldn't expect it to work, it does: https://ideone.com/LUxcLX Don't have easy access to a linux box or a desire to figure out why though. As others have said, you'd be better off sticking to standard types if you want your code to be portable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is supposedly a problem with GLIBC. See https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59945 and Jonathan Wakely's answer.

Glibc defines it:

```
#ifdef __USE_MISC
/* Old compatibility names for C types.  */
typedef unsigned long int ulong;
typedef unsigned short int ushort;
typedef unsigned int uint;
#endif
```

__USE_MISC is defined because G++ defines _GNU_SOURCE, which is well known to cause problems, e.g. PR 11196 and PR 51749

This particular namespace pollution only occurs with C++11 because  only needs to #include  in C++11 mode to define std::to_string, std::stoi etc. but in general the problem affects C++98 too.

Comment: Thank you! Interesting indeed.